# Regex to rearrange ebook file names

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex to rearrange ebook file names, for use in File Renamer. The file names have an old library reference code at the begging of the series information which is in square brackets at the end of the file name. I need to remove the code and rearrange the file names so the series info is in the middle. Example:

```
"Author Name - Book Tile [HMED-584, Series info 02].txt"
```

Needs to become:

```
Author Name - [Series info 02] - Book Title.txt
```

I used this regex before to remove the old library reference codes that were in their own square brackets separate from the series info:

```
\[[A-Z]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,4}(, *[A-Z]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,4})?]
```

I'm fairly new to regex so haven't tried anything on these yet.

Comment: Are `Author Name` and `Book Title` constants ?

Comment: Something like this: http://regex101.com/r/tI2cB1/1

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
(.*?)\s*-\s*(.*?)\s*\[(?:[A-Z]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,4},\s*)+([^\]]+)\]\.([a-z]+)
```

Will capture the following groups:

1. Author Name
2. Book Title
3. Series Info
4. File Extension

So that you can replace with this:

```
$1 - [$3] - $2.$4
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/sT3wC4/2)

---

I made Author Name and Book Title lazy dot-match-all capture groups. You can replace these (`.*?`) with things more specific like `[\w\s]+`, but I don't think it is worth it. Then I match your same "4 alpha"-"4 digit" pattern for the Reference Code but throw it in a repeating, non-capturing group. This is followed by any non-`]` characters for the Series Info (you can change this to another lazy dot-match-all, if you want).  Finally, I capture the file extension..but this part can be left off (or hard coded in) of the match/replace if it is always `.txt`.

Comment: I had to use $ signs in the Replace instead of \ for File Renamer but otherwise worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @Zarnia glad it worked for you. Sometimes, depending on the software/language, you need to use `$` for backreferences.

Comment: Just noticed it missed the double-barrel library ref codes. If you look above at the expression I used to remove the original codes that were in their own square brackets, it was designed to cope with single or double codes, for example: [HRS-936, MTS-760, Series name 01]

Comment: @Zarnia updated to allow for repetitive matching of the reference code.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
 # Find:    ([^-]+?)\s*-\s*([^\[]+?)\s*\[[^,]*?,\s*([^\]]+?)\s*\]
 # Replace: $1 - [$3] - $2

 ( [^-]+? )                    # (1), Name
 \s* 
 - 
 \s*                           
 ( [^\[]+? )                   # (2), Title
 \s* 
 \[
 [^,]*? 
 ,
 \s*                           
 (                             # (3 start), Series
      [^\]]+? 
 )                             # (3 end)
 \s* 
 \]
```